# How to pass multiple parameters to orchestrator for Azure Durable function using PowerShell

Tags: azure-functions

I have Azure durable functions for HTTP starter, orchestrator and activity using PowerShell.

I'm trying to pass two string parameters from the starter to the orchestrator but the orchestrator just crashes with an unknown error. Even if I call Start-DurableOrchestration and pass -InputObject "X" then the orchestrator's $Context parameter isn't "X".

How do I pass the two parameters and read them in the orchestrator?

The starter code:

```
$Parameters = @{ Value1 = "X"; Value2 = "Y" }
$InstanceId = Start-DurableOrchestration -FunctionName "TestFunction" -InputObject $Parameters
```

The orchestrator code:

```
param($Context)
$Value1 = $Context.Value1    # Doesn't contain the expected value
#$Value1 = $Context.Body.Value1   # Doesn't work if I tried this instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the below way to pass **multiple parameters** to **Orchestrator function** from **Starter function** and read those values using PowerShell Azure Durable function:

**Starter function:**

```
param($Request,  $TriggerMetadata)

$Parameters  =  @{ Value1  =  "X"; Value2  =  "Y" }

$FunctionName  =  $Request.Params.FunctionName

$InstanceId  =  Start-DurableOrchestration  -FunctionName $FunctionName  -Input $Parameters
```

**Orchestrator function:**

```
param($Context)
//print values from the input object

$output  +=  Invoke-DurableActivity  -FunctionName 'Hello'  -Input $Context.Input.Value1.Value

$output  +=  Invoke-DurableActivity  -FunctionName 'Hello'  -Input $Context.Input.Value2.Value
```

**Activity function:**

```
param($name)

"Hello $name!"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]